# Как работает четырёхадресная машина?

Tags: информатика

Подскажите , как это работает?

[image]

Comment: Мне кажется (но могу и ошибаться), что на приведенной схеме ошибочка. 

Видимо результат команды должен записываться а память не по адресу "Уменьшаемое", а по адресу "Разность".

==

Четырехадресная команда отличается от трехадресной 

(ее формат: *`COP OP1,OP2,RESULT`*) 

наличием адреса перехода к следующей команде. Во всех остальных архитектурах выбирается следующая по порядку команда.

==

Инфа по запросу "четырехадресная ЭВМ" в инете есть.

==

Вообще (IMHO) четырехадресная  архитектура это скорее академическое упражнение, может и были когда-то такие железки, но мне они неизвестны.

Comment: Мне кажется, на схеме просто показано, что рез-т команды записывается в память. 
Спасибо Вам!

Comment: @alias, вероятно Вы правы. Просто глаз как-то сразу по схеме пробежал... и остановился на "Уменьшаемом"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тут временно можно посмотреть вашу книгу: [архитектура базовой ЭВМ](http://view.samurajdata.se/psview.php?id=30b2a2b5&page=4&all=1).
А [тут](http://window.edu.ru/library/pdf2txt/816/72816/50681/page3) скачать в PDF.

Называется Архитектура базовой ЭВМ ('2010). Базовая - имеется в виду [архитектура Фон-Неймана](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0_%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0). Нашел книгу запросом "адрес следующей команды" "адрес результата" "адрес вычитаемого" "адрес уменьшаемого" (один и верный результат - удивительно не правда ли).
То есть ответ очевиден: По ссылке, под рисунком 1.9 в книге всё расписано.

Все вопросы от микропрограммирования, схемотехники (бинарной логики), программирования на уровне сигналов... и прочее и прочее - относится к компьютерным вопросам. К вопросам, которые вы изучали в ВУЗе

welcome :)

Comment: Iranda, вы в курсе что единственная, оставленная вами ссылка на книжку исчезнет в течение суток? (pdf конвертер не держит в кеше долго)